# Why we have to check both additivity and homogenity for linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra

$f: V \to W $ over $K$ with $a,b \in V$ and $k \in K$.

Additivity: $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$

Homogenity: $k*f(b) =f(k * b)$

I have a visual understanding that a function is linear if the structure is kept while projecting it with $f$ but why it is not enough to check if the function is additive?

I would be glad to have some easy examples and an intuition why we would have to check both conditions.

Comment: My intuition is: f(k*a)=f(a+...+a)= f(a)+...+f(a)=k*f(a), so if a function is additive, it MUST be homogenous. Where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: That argument only works if $k\in \mathbb Q$.  You can't get all of $\mathbb R$ that way.

Comment: For that reason:  if you add continuity (or some similar property) you can get the rest of the way.  You'll see from the linked duplicate that the counterexamples are wildly discontinuous.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Brings me closer to understand that duplicate thread